# The Y coordinate is returning an inverted value

Tags: java, android, coordinates

I'm trying to get **X** and **Y** coordinates when I call `onTouchListener()` method.

In my app, I've a `GLSuerfaceView` called `renderView` contains `mainBitmap`, I'm tying to move a drawn object in `renderView` using finger :

```
renderView.setOnTouchListener((v, motionEvent) -> {
           int x = (int) motionEvent.getX();
           int y = (int) motionEvent.getY();
           int projectedX = (int) ((double) x * ((double) mainBitmap.getWidth() / (double) renderView.getWidth()));
           int projectedY = (int) ((double) y * ((double) mainBitmap.getHeight() / (double) renderView.getHeight()));
           currentFilter.setCoordinate(projectedX, projectedY);
           return true;
           });
```

The `projectedX` is returning the correct value, but `projectedY` is returning an inverted value.

***For example, if I move my finger to the top the object that I want to move is moving down instead of top***

Comment: In Android, the coordinate system is like in this picture (inverted height): https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*o1I8eC5nQdyuAABzJYg3iQ.png

Comment: @AlekseyVoko thank you for your comment, I'm really confused now, do you have any idea how I can calculate the Y value based on the height of the view

Comment: I do not know for sure. If you look at the coordinate plane, then the smaller Y the higher on the screen.